# How do I dynamically make a field type number in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am generating an HTML form from JSON using some custom directives. Part of the JSON include restrictions on the values of the fields.

One of the restrictions the JSON puts on fields is a positive decimal type. The code I use in my link function to accomplish this:

```
//...snip
if (<this field should be number>) {
   elem.attr("type", "number");
}
```

This successfully changes the field type to `number`. However, there are two problems:

1. It does not allow negative numbers
2. Every time I type a key stroke (even for valid numbers), it throws a number format exception. For example, if I type "123" I will get the following 3 errors:

   - `Error: [ngModel:numfmt] 1 to be a number`
   - `Error: [ngModel:numfmt] Expected 12 to be a number`
   - `Error: [ngModel:numfmt] Expected 123 to be a number`

I know that the model is successfully changed to a number type because when I print it out with a directive it displays without quotes.

So my question is:

1. How do I allow negative numbers
2. How do I stop all of the exceptions from being

Comment: Works fine in this [DEMO on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/udt9snzb/).

Comment: Why do you need `$compile`? The `type` property is an intrinsic part of the `input` element. See [MDN HTML Element Reference -- input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input).

Comment: @georgeawg Thank you. You were right that I did not need `$compile`. I now can't get the field to show validation errors for some reason but that might be for a separate question.

Comment: You should show the code for your directive. You didn't show that you were using `$compile` and readers need to see how you interact with  `ngModelController`.

Comment: @georgeawg Thank you again for your help as it has set me on the right track. I think there may be other issues in my code and I don't want to dump it on StackOverflow so I will try to get those into manageable pieces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### How to Dynamically Change the Type of an Input Element

The type of an `input` element can be changed dynamically simply with AngularJS interpolation.

```
<input type="{{dynamicType}}" ng-model="inputValue">
```

Or from a directive

```
angular.module("myApp").directive("typeVar", function() {
     return {
         link: linkFn
     };
     function linkFn(scope,elem,attrs) {
         //elem.attr("type", "number");  
         attrs.$observe("typeVar", function(value) {
             elem.attr("type", value);
             //attrs.$set("type", value);
         });
     }
});
```

HTML

```
<input type-var="{{dynamicType}}" ng-model="inputValue">
```

The [DEMO on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/udt9snzb/)

The `type` property is an intrinsic part of the `input` element. For more information, see [MDN HTML Element Reference -- input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input).